# What are the default expressions of skewness and kurtosis used in Scipy?

Tags: kurtosis, scipy

Scipy's (to date, version 0.19.1) [Statistical Functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) module (aka `scipy.stats`) contains the functions of [scipy.stats.skew](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html#scipy.stats.skew) and [scipy.stats.kurtosis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html#scipy.stats.kurtosis) to compute *skewness* and *kurtosis* of a data set (3rd and 4th statistical moments, respectively). Moreover, [scipy.stats.describe](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.describe.html#scipy.stats.describe) calls these functions.

The definitions of skewness and kurtosis may vary; hence, no consensus on them in the literature. Then, which mathematical expressions are used in Scipy to define skewness and kurtosis in the two aforementioned functions with their default settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [scipy.stats.skew](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html#scipy.stats.skew) and [scipy.stats.kurtosis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html#scipy.stats.kurtosis) call the function of [scipy.stats.moment](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html#scipy.stats.moment), which computes the following for the k-th central moment of a data sample:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script> <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts:["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" }, TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none" });   </script>

$$m_k = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^k$$
```

Accordingly, [scipy.stats.skew](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html#scipy.stats.skew) with default settings (e.g. `bias=True`) computes:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script> <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts:["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" }, TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none" });   </script>

$$ S = \frac{m_3}{(m_2)^{1.5}} $$
```

[scipy.stats.kurtosis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html#scipy.stats.kurtosis) with default settings:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script> <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts:["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" }, TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none" });   </script>

$$ K = \frac{m_4}{(m_2)^{2}} $$
```